# How work around type system's shallow interface matching? (covariant result types)

Tags: go, types

The delightful golang's interface matching seems to only go one layer deep. It matches the concrete structs (or their pointers) to interfaces as they are presented, but, if they are wrapped in anything, matching fails.

This also affects channels: the types of values they pass are not eligible for interface compatibility checks.

Minimal illustration:

```golang
type I0 interface{ fn0() }
type I1 interface{ fn1() I0 }

type S0 struct{}

func (s *S0) fn0() {}

type S1 struct{}

func (s *S1) fn1() *S0 { return &S0{} }
```

[View in playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mD-RIDUg2Iy)

Now in this trivial example it's possible to just adapt `S1`'s `fn1` return type, but I'd like to later use a type switch to recover original type *without* invoking the function.

---

The function case is mentioned in Go's FAQ as [covariant result types](https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types).

Comment: It's just not possible.  There is an interesting discussion about it when it was proposed to change the language to allow it but the proposal got rejected (I still hold out hope for Go 2!) https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12754

Comment: The posted code isn't violating interface rules, it's violating basic type safety. The function signature states it returns a `*S1`, then tries to return a `*S0` instead. The interfaces defined are irrelevant.

Comment: i agree with Adrian. the example code is plainly wrong. apart, from S1 point of view, it is forbidden to return S0, as fn1 explicitly defines that it returns an S1, that is a well defined struct.

Comment: @Adrian that was not intentional; fixed now.